# How to go to next page in an API call

Tags: javascript

Totally new version of this question. I am working with the disputes API from Klarna to create a table inside [Retool](https://retool.com/) to create a table of all my disputes. The Klarna API is a little confusing to me as I don't know how to get all the data from the API

#### The Problem

I want to get all 866 results from the Klarna API into my table in Retool. Currently, by adjusting the `limit` query parameter, I can decide how much elements I want. However, the limit for this is 250 elements. When running the API call in Hoppscotch with a limit of 1, I get this result:

```
{
  "pagination": {
    "limit": 1,
    "count": 1,
    "total": 687,
    "next_page": [
      "1678799406473",
      "205362922"
    ]
  },
  "disputes": [
    {
      "dispute_krn": "krn:klarna:eu1:dispute:return:205362922",
      "investigation_status": "closed",
      "reason": "return",
      "opened_at": "2023-03-14T13:10:06.473Z",
      "closed_at": "2023-06-22T10:36:52.206Z",
      "closing_reason": "resolved",
      "capture_id": "a1c5f37b-7009-4852-a451-f96860a04322",
      "region": "eu1",
      "order": {
        // A lot of data that is not important
      ],
      "status": "closed",
      "disputed_amount": {
        "amount": 69900,
        "currency": "SEK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### What I've figured out until now

I've figured out that the value at the index 1 in the array `next_page` is the cursor to the dispute ID. The dispute ID can be found as the last value in the string with the key `dispute_krn`. This thus probably means that this is the cursor and this API works with cursor-based pagination. I have no idea what the first value stands for and I cannot find anything about that in the [Klarna API docs](https://docs.klarna.com/api/disputes-api/disputes-api_2.0.0/).

#### Solution I am looking for

Most likely, I am going to be using a JavaScript loop that fires the API query again and again until there is no next page anymore. This would not be too difficult for me to solve, however, I don't know where to find the next page so to say. I'm still pretty new to coding as you might have guessed and the APIs that I have worked with until this point have all been using page-based pagination which is a lot simpler to use.

**Can anybody guide me in the right direction?**

Comment: well, very bad question.  API-Docu? How do you call it?

Comment: https://api.klara.ch/docs points to https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/; very well documented

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your query string the `next_page` values as an array specifying multiple times the `next_page[]` key:

> {{YOUR_BASE_URL}}?next_page[]=1678799406473&next_page[]=205362922

It worked for me.